# mistake in install package and replace default files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget-package

I was looking for a package that can send email verification for users, and i found a webpage for install ASP.NET Identity 2.0

i'm beginner in asp. 
According to the Website Directory i use this command in package manager `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre` and after process is done i found some of my file's content replace with default values. now i'm very angry because i have a lot of code in my files.

Is there a way to restore files?

please help me.

Comment: Do you have any backup / source control system ?

Comment: no, what do u mean about source control system?